# Cannot use jsdom as a package in a meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm

So I have a packages.json -

```
    {
      "jsdom" : "0.8.0",
      "request" : "2.25.0"
    }
```

and I'm doing this,

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.startup(function () {

      var _ = Npm.require("underscore");

      var jsdom = Npm.require("jsdom");
      var request = Npm.require("request");
       });
    }
```

but, I get "Error: Cannot find module 'jsdom'". Why?

Comment: Is that the entire `package.json` or just a snippet? Does `npm ls` mention `jsdom` and `request`? Any `ERR!`s in the output?

Answer (score 0):

So this was resolved by doing Meteor.require("jsdom");

Comment: For future visitors: As for now it's  Meteor.npmRequire("jsdom")